# faster way to do simple tracking of line and column information than a case statement

Tags: c++, performance, text, whitespace, fgetc

I'm running into trouble where on a release build I'm losing about 7-8MB/s of throughput due to a simple case statement:

```
switch(ch) {
    case '\t': // tab
        m_column+=TabWidth; // tabwidth is static const
        break;
    case '\n': // newline
        ++m_line;
        // fall through
    case '\r': // carriage return
        m_column=0;
        break;
    default:
        ++m_column;
        break;
}
```

m_column and m_line are declared unsigned long int, and ch is an int16_t (because fget and my read routine can return negative values)

Here's with it commented

```
utf8 scanned 20383269 characters in 298.871000 ms at 63.572578MB/s
```

and with it uncommented

```
utf8 scanned 20383269 characters in 334.665000 ms at 56.773191MB/s
```

My results from running multiple times are pretty consistent, within a megabyte or two, and if one is slower for a run, they both are.

This isn't the only place I need to increase performance but if there's a better way to do this part it will probably help me in other places in my code too. I switch a lot on characters because this is a JSON parser. So I'm hoping with this question it will lead me to technique I can apply elsewhere as well.

don't worry about the utf8 encoding. I've turned it off for now. that's just the console message

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: The `+=Tabwidth` is not correct if there is already text in the 'column'.  Are you pre-filling the line; if not then tab will lead to garbage.

Comment: I should be doing tab computation by dividing the screen. However, in my experience I've been using this to track my position through 20MB of pretty printed JSON and it has worked. This position tracking is for debugging only since it shows your physical, not logical position anyway so it's not very useful to the end user unless they know how to translate physical to logical themselves

Comment: Sorry Rick, I should have put a tag. I put fgetc and figured it was enough. mea culpa. it's C++ on linux using gcc. I *just* found out I was using the wrong compiler option for optimizations. I'm kinda new to gcc coming from a windows background. i was just about to close the question

Comment: Don't close it -- My Answer (I think) provides a general optimization principle.

Comment: I had closed it before i saw your post, or maybe before you made it. I'm not sure how to open it again

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong compiler options for gcc. It should have been -O3

Answer (score 1):

The code given tests every printable character for not being `\n`, `\r`, or `\t`.  Sinc printable characters are presumably the most common characters, let's optimize them...

This will speed it up a little:

```
if (ch >= ' ') {
    ++m_column;
} else {
    switch ...
}
```

Comment: In my use case control characters are the least common since i'm usually dealing with machine generated json which is almost always minified. That said, it's important to be able to track the location if you're reading pretty printed JSON to debug your queries or something (this is a pull parser. not in memory trees) - so i made an option to turn it off and on which can speed things up a little

Answer (score 0):

As already proposed, one can speed things up slightly by arranging the comparisons in the order of frequency. Also one can try to remove branches completely (noticing, that e.g. arm7, arm64 and intel x64 instruction sets can handle simple comparisons without branches.)

```
static const int8_t tabs[16] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,tabWidth,0,1,1,0,1,1};
ch = ch < 16 ? ch : 15;  // typically branch free
m_column += tabs[ch];    // single load and increment
m_line += ch == '\n';
m_column &= ch == '\r' ? 0 : -1;  // clear the column conditionally
```

One can pack several conditions into the `int8_t tabs` array, e.g. bit 7 = column clear flag, bit 6 = 1 for `\n` to be used as `m_line += (table[ch] >> 6) & 1;`.

Comment: I actually tried that before I figured out my problem was my compiler options. Maybe I should try it in a release build. Edit: I just tried it and it significantly slowed things down. Serves me right for trying to outsmart the compiler. I wouldn't have tried but my perf results were so bad at first.

Comment: It's definitely worth to try outsmart compilers on significant problems. Even if this technique doesn't work for you with your generic distribution of data, it might work with other data. The only thing to be done is to measure (in release mode with all the optimisations turned on.)

Comment: Oh I agree with you, it's just half the time it doesn't work. I did away with the tracking altogether because it speeds my code up in other ways. I'm looking for GB/s throughput on a modern machine. It's over half a gig a second to search for all JSON fields with a particular name in the document, on my rickety old machine so I'm good now.